# CKEditor WYSIWYG - Can't use link dialogue to create links (OK button doesn't work)

Tags: ckeditor, wysiwyg

When trying to create a link using CKEditor, the OK button will not work, and the dialogue box will not close ('cancel' works).

Is anyone else seeing this?

We are on  CiviCRM 5.3.1 on Apache, Drupal 7 using jquery 1.7 on our admin theme. We have tested this and seen the same behaviour in CiviMail and CiviEvent.

The fault appears in Chrome on Mac & PC, though it is fine on Edge (where the OK & Cancel buttons appear the other way round to the screenshot below)

[image: Screenshot of CKEditor Dialogue Box]

Comment: The same thing is happening in WP 4.9.7 / Civi 5.3.1

Comment: Have you tried this on the demo sites? Looks OK there to me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

JQuery update settings:
Set alternate jQuery version for admin pages to: 1.5

Make sure CiviCRM theme module is installed

In Appearance -> set CiviCRM Administration theme to Adminimal (or some other Admin theme)

You’ll want admin jquery 1.5 for many admin pages on your drupal site to work well. Here’s a reference: https://www.drupal.org/project/views/issues/1965674

Comment: Hi,  switching the admin theme (Garland) over to Jquery 1.5 worked as a workaround, thank you.  I had previously tried switching over to the theme 'stark', but it didn't affect this problem. Not sure if there are any unforseen consequences from flipping over to jquery 1.5, but it does seem to work as a workaround. Thanks.

Comment: Lots of admin eg views work well with jquery 1.5 on admin - so it’s our default on all admin; so it’s not a workaround - you want jquery 1.5 on admin for many of your Drupal site/admin pages to function well